# how can I use php variables and symfony helpers in javascript

Tags: symfony-1.4

I've got some symfony template files with `<script>` chunks, obviously this needs to be in the head.

these chunks of javascript make use of helpers like `url_for` and also echo out symfony template variables.

I need to be able to load this javascript using `include_javascript` or similar but what is the best  way to still use the symfony templating functions and access the variables I need to generate the script while loading it into the head not the body of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I use a particular Symfony module, that fills JavaScript variables with PHP code.

To do so, you can create a module called "javascript" for example, which has a single action in it. The template associated to this action must be have the following name : ...Success.js.php.

In this template, you can fill your JavaScript variables like this :

```
    var global = {
        misc: {
            userCulture : "<?php echo $sf_user->getCulture() ?>",
            serverName : "<?php echo $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]?>",
        },
    ...
    }
```

Then, in your *appName*Configuration.class.php (located in the config folder of your app), you must add the following code :

```
    class indexConfiguration extends sfApplicationConfiguration
    {
        public function configure()
        {
          $this->dispatcher->connect('context.load_factories', array($this, 'listenToContextLoadFactoriesEvent'));
        }

        public function listenToContextLoadFactoriesEvent(sfEvent $event)
        {
                $event->getSubject()->getResponse()->addJavascript($event->getSubject()->getRouting()->generate('javascript_variables'));
        }
    }
```

Then, you must add the following route to your routing.yml file :

```
    javascript_variables:
      url:    /*moduleName*/*actionName*.:sf_format
      param:  { module: *moduleName*, action: *actionName*, sf_format: js }
```

Now, you're able to access these JavaScript variables in any of your js files, i.e. :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            alert(global.misc.userCulture);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, I would never have known this approach. One issue is that I don't need access to the same variables for every template so this 'global' approach seems like it isn't quite a full fit , the variables I'm using are much more module/action specific and what variiables I am using change by module and action (for example - a url for ajax submission changes across module actions) could this approach be adapted to serve this need?

Comment: In the template, you can create the JavaScript variables you'll need according to the current module. For example, $module = $sf_context->getModuleName(); switch ($module) { case "admin": var global = “... “}.